# php SimpleXml & arrays issue

Tags: php, simplexml

When I `print_r($var)` I get the result below.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [SEND_FILE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [FILEID] => 123
            [GUID] => 456
            [SUMMARY] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [NB_PAYMENTS] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

**How can I get the value of the FILEID element in a variable?** If I do

`print $result->SEND_FILE->FILEID[0]`

then I just get the number - what I want, no mention of a SimpleXML Object.
But if I put this variable in an array, as such

```
$res['file_id'] = $result->SEND_FILE->FILEID[0]
```

and then `print_r($res)` I get:

```
Array
    (
        [file_id] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => 307466
            )
    )
```

How can I get it to remove the `[0] / SimpleXMLElement Object`?

Comment: SimpleXml is not an array. It only behaves *remotely* like one.

Comment: Understood but ... I'm trying to send this array to a web service but the file_id key has to be just a numeric value, not an SimpleXML Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will look not too elegant, but try casting the result to integer (if the type is known):

```
$res['file_id'] = (int)$result->SEND_FILE->FILEID[0]
```

Comment: Confirmed, casting necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you append the `[0]` at the end? You dont need that. You should simply do

```
print $result->SEND_FILE->FILEID;
```

And that should be enough.